# On the Characterization of $F[\alpha]$ for a Field Extension $E/F$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let $E/F$ be a field extension. Reading a proof that
$$
\alpha \text{ is algebraic over } F \implies [F[\alpha]:F] < \infty,
$$
one might begin by considering an element $f(\alpha) \in F[\alpha]$ and **its corresponding polynomial in $F[x]$**. Then, if $n := \deg m$ where $m(x)$ is the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $K$, Euclidean division shows that $\{ 1, \alpha, \ldots, \alpha^{n-1} \}$ is a generating set for the vector space $F[\alpha]$ over $F$.

**Question:** I believe that I can prove that
$$
F[\alpha] = \left\{ \sum_{i=0}^n a_i \alpha^i : a_i \in F \right\},
$$
but since it seems to not have been proved or even mentioned before in the text, I wonder if it is supposed to be trivial?

I do know that there is a corresponding result for ideals. If $A$ is a ring and $E \subseteq A$ is a non-empty subset, we may define $(E)$ to be the smallest ideal of $A$ containing $E$, that is,
$$
(E) := \bigcap_{\substack{J \text{ ideal} \\ J \supseteq E}} J.
$$
Then one can *prove* (and does it)
$$
(E) = \left\{ \sum_{k=1}^n r_k a_k : r_k \in A, a_k \in E \right\}.
$$

Comment: Is the sum supposed to end at $n-1$? I don't think it's trivial, but it might be an immediate consequence of something that precedes it in the proof. For example, it is equivalent to the fact you mentioned that $F[\alpha]$ is generated as an $F$-vector space by $1, \alpha, \alpha^2, \dots \alpha^{n-1}$. It's not clear whether you're saying that this had already been stated in the proof. I think you might need to post the proof, or at least more details about it, for a meaningful answer.

Comment: @Dave Well, in my question, initially the sum is over all finite combinations, so $n$ is not fixed. Then if $n = \deg m$, indeed the *proof* of the result I mention first shows that we may only consider the sums from $0$ to $n-1$.

Comment: The proof goes like this : Let $m$ be the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $F$. Then $f(x) = q(x) m(x)+r(x)$ where $\deg r < \deg m$. But $f(\alpha) = r(\alpha)$ therefore if $n := \deg m$, then $f(\alpha) = \displaystyle \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} b_i \alpha^i$ for some $b_i \in F$. Hence in the proof we use the characterization of $F[\alpha]$, that has not been proved before.

Comment: @Dave No, it seems to me that the proof uses the fact that we can write any element in $F[\alpha]$ as $f(\alpha)$ for some $f(x) \in F[x]$.

Comment: And that's the fact that may or may not be trivial?

Comment: @Dave That's it. So since you seem to say that it is *not* trivial, it comforts me.

Comment: No, I misunderstood your question, because I thought $n$ had a specific meaning. In fact, it *is* more or less trivial. Most likely, the definition of $F[\alpha]$ is as the subring generated by $F \cup \{\alpha\}$ inside some big field $L$ that contains all the elements of interest. It should be clear that this is the set of all elements $f(\alpha)$ for $f \in F[X]$. You'd just need to check that each $f(\alpha)$ is in the subring generated, and second, that the set of all such $f(\alpha)$ does form a subring of $L$.

Comment: Sorry, take $L = E$ here. Also, the last part can be proved most elegantly by considering the image of the ring homomorphism $h_\alpha \colon F[X] \rightarrow E$ defined by $h_{\alpha}(f) = f(\alpha)$. This is the "evaluation homomorphism" at $\alpha$. A more straightforward proof may be more instructive, however.